# How to define a clickable area in an image used in ImageView

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to define a clickable area in an image? Something equivalent or similar to map-area tags in HTML? Or is there a standard way of doing this sort of thing?

Answer (score 3):

A possible method

1) get the width, and height of the image view using (in pixels)

2) get the coordinates of the image view (which is the top left corner of the image view)

3) create a touch listener, and record the coordinates of the users touch

4) if the user's touch coordinates fall on the image do whatever you want to

If you only want to do certain things based on where the user touches you will have to calculate the coordinates of those regions using the coordinates of the image view, and the image views width and height.

Comment: I will give this a try and mark it as correct. If i can get the coordinates as you mentioned above, then i could overcome the problem. TIA

Comment: ok, I am going to sleep, so I won't reply anymore. Remember that the coordinates of the image view will be the top left corner, and that the left most x coord =  the image view's x coords, and the right most x coord = the image view's x coord + the width. The y coords are the same, but swap where I put x with y, and width for height.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be no standard way for this, but you can achieve it by placing a transparent VIEW over your imageview. Set click listener to that view and make imageview clickable false.

Comment: This is what i had done previously, This is okay if the clickable areas are square shaped. But when more complex areas are in the play, we have to define more clickable area than what we really need so that everything is overlapped nicely.

Answer (score 0):

When i have to do something similar, i use an include view.

As for the layout the include view will be accessing, i would use **FrameLayout** as root.

Its children would be the **ImageView** that i want to depict, along with a **LinearLayout** infront of it containing Buttons at the positions i want the user to choose from.

Then in code, i set listeners to these buttons.

Lastly, i would set the buttons so that there background is transparent and text is not available.

**For example** in a project i am working on, i have an ImageView with an Image of Ocean as background.

In front of the view i have a LinearLayout with smaller ImageViews with images of islands.

I place listener on the islands to see when they are clicked to open a new activity.